# How to remove the leading 0s and divide the remaining value by 100, use a dot separator between the integer and the decimal part in C#

Tags: c#, .net

for example let's just say I have a:

var value = "0000000000002022"

how can I get : 20.22

Comment: `var division = float.Parse(value) / 100;`, mathematically speaking, it doesn't matter how many zeroes are in front of your non-zero number `000002 = 2` is true

Comment: I always recommend using TryParse just to be sure the string value is the expected

Comment: Thank you !! @MindSwipe and J.Salas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, it doesn't matter how many zeroes are before your number, their the same, so `0000002 = 2` is true. We can use this fact to simply parse our string to a number, and then do the division, but we have to be a little careful in which number type we use, because doing `(int) 16 / (int) 5` will result in `3`, which obviously isn't correct, but integer division does that. So, just to be sure we don't loose any precision, we'll use `float`

```cs
string value = "0000000000002022";
if (float.TryParse(value, out var number))
{
    // Successfully parsed our string to a float
    Console.WriteLine(number / 100);
}
else
{
    // We failed to parse our string to a float :(
    Console.WriteLine($"Could not parse '{value}' to a float");
}
```

Always use `TryParse` except if you're 110% sure the given string will always be a number, and even then, circumstances can (and will, this is software development after all) change.

Note: `float` isn't infinitely large, it has a maximum and minimum value, and anything outside that range cannot be represented by a float. Plus, floating point numbers also have a caveat: They're not 100% accurate, for example `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is false, you can read up more on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/9363973). If you need to be as accurate as possible, for example when working with money, then maybe use `decimal` instead (or, make the decision to represent the money as a whole number, representing the minor units of currency your country uses)

Comment: thanks for the reply but I am getting below error:  Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Comment: it's good if we convert value like below :  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(value )/ 100);

Comment: Oops, I mixed up the variables, instead of `value / 100` it should be `number / 100`, fixed it. You can also use `decimal.TryParse` instead

Comment: Already I have done with number / 100  thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

by using convert

```
Int16.Parse(value);
Convert.ToDecimal(int1)/100;
```

Comment: That would do integer division and result in 20 not 20.22.

Comment: @juharr please check all with example.

Comment: So you are doing `string -> int -> decimal -> divide`. Isn't far more easier is you do `string -> decimal -> divide`?

Comment: Please don't post images of code